# How to determine if attribute exists using rational test workbench

Tags: testing, ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I started using Rational Test Workbench to test my mobile application. At current time I am trying to test login functionality and I faced the probem. I do not know how add a verification point to determine if attribute (in my case login button) exists to know if it went to the second page or not. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

first, select an action where your "login" button appear in your test

in the "mobile data view", select button you want to test. it will appear with a red rectangle around :

[image: mobile data view]

click on "element tab to see the view hierarchy of the screen at this moment. select your "login" button there, right click and create a verification point on one of its property

[image: creating verification point]

during test execution, if the button do not appear, you'll see an error saying "object not found"

Hope it helps

Jerome Bozier

Senior Software Engineer, RTW mobile Android, IBM